# how can I fix this error in Mathematica: argument at position 1 should be a machine-size real number?

Tags: save, wolfram-mathematica

I have a code on mathematica which is working perfectly. I need to save the results and call them back in another code. But when I do and try to recall the result I have this error (see image attached). It seems that The part of the code saving the result is not working properly. here is the code for saving:

```
filename = "solutions/soltest_26aout";
Block[{FullDefinition = Definition}, 
  Save[filename, {interP2CM, inter\[Xi]a2CM, inter\[Xi]b2CM, solp, 
    sol\[Xi], sol\[Zeta], h, gridx, gridv, Nx, Nv, minx, maxx, minva, 
    maxva, minvb, maxvb, S, L, LRva, LRvb, a, A, 
    B, \[Sigma]a, \[Sigma]b, \[Rho], \[Gamma], \[Psi], \[Phi], \
\[Tau], \[Delta], Veq, Ueq, inter\[Sigma]ax2CM, inter\[Sigma]bx2CM, 
    interpiab2CM, interpia2CM, interpib2CM, interpiba2CM, 
    inter\[Sigma]ap2CM, inter\[Sigma]bp2CM, interr2CM, inter\[Mu]x2CM,
     interg2CM, intersa2CM, SSx2CM}]
  ];
```

Now after I call the solution like:

```
<< "solutions/soltest_26aout";
```

and this is the error messages I got:[click here to see the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wMsc.jpg)
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Cannot tell if it is everything, but the error message seems to clearly show that the functions interξa2CM, interξb2CM didn't evaluate to numeric results because in the messages you see things like interξa2CM[...stuff...] and interξb2CM[...stuff...] instead of things like 12.3 and 119*10^23. Can you figure out why those functions didn't evaluate to numeric results?

Comment: Thanks @Bill for your contribution. I executed interξb2CM to see what is inside. It contains numeric values.